# Visual Studio Community 2019 Publish Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I trying to publish my application through a file system and it throws the following error.

[image: screenshot]

```
17-04-2021 09:41:43
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
```

Please do let me know as am struggling with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, it use to work and for the last week it gives me that error. I'm publishing from .net core 5 app to Azure Linux. The only work around I have found is publishing to folder, then uploading the files by ftp.